# Ajax Validation Without Persist

Tags: java, seam

HI all,

I'm trying to set some validation in my Seam application & I have it working but it has a few side effects I'd like to avoid.  I've set up the fields on my input form like below:

```
<label for="displayName" class="required">Display Name:</label>
<s:decorate id="displayNameDecorate" styleClass="errorwrapper">
    <h:inputText id="displayName" value="#{presenceHome.instance.displayName}" required="true">
        <a4j:support event="onblur" reRender="displayNameDecorate" ajaxSingle="true"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
        <h:message for="displayName" styleClass="errormessage"/>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</s:decorate>
```

This method works fine.  If I enter a value that is considered invalid for display name, then it shows a validation error.  The trouble I have is when the value entered is valid.  When I tab out the field, the a4j:support fires off causing the data to be validated (which passes) and then **persisted**.  Now if after tabbing into the next field I decide that I didn't want to edit this record, I can't cancel out, reverting my changes - my changes have already been persisted to the DB.

Is there anyway I can have the AJAX validation fire off but without any persistence occurring?  Or do I just need to forget about the ajax validation and live with it firing off on form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happening in the code you're showing, but would using something like Richfaces' ***< rich:ajaxValidator >*** not make life easier? The doc page is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_ajaxValidator.html)

Comment: I hadn't seen that RichFaces tag before. First one in the feature list states "Skips all JSF processing except validation" which is exactly want I want. So thanks for pointing it out.